# API call (fetch) with user token through JavaScript (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data (in React with JS) from a website X (that has cors-enabled) but need first to get a user token from a website Y and I don't know how to figure that out. Somehow I think that I have to get the user token from Y, save it in a variable and add it as a header on the other call but I'm kinda lost with the GET/POST methods.

By now what I have is this but somehow doesn't work, I think I'm not sending properly the head or making the actual calls correctly:

```
getToken(){
  const url = 'websiteOfTheToken';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    userToken: data.image
  });
}
```

And:

```
getData(){
 const response = await fetch('websiteOfTheData', {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', 
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: '' // I don't know what is this doing
    }) 
    }).catch( error => {
    console.log('Error fetching and parsing data ', error)
    });

  this.setState({
    data: response.json()
  });
}
```

Comment: FYI `await` isn't valid in synchronous functions. Can you provide a "working" example where you call the first fetch and try to use the saved token in the second fetch?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I want to say / ask about:

1. Typically you get the token after a successfull login, so a standard request for a token would be a post request with the user data.
2. An `await` in javascript works only inside `async` functions, read about it.
3. The most common practice for handling api responses (Promise) is to use `then-catch` blocks, read about it.
4. A typical JWT header you need to attach to your requests looks like this: `"Authorization": "Bearer theactualtoken1234"`.
5. The `body` of the `fetch` post request is the actual data you're sending to the server. So its contents are totally arbitrary - I also don't have an idea what this `"title": ""` is doing...